# Converting word to vector using GloVe

Tags: python, deep-learning, stanford-nlp, gensim

I loaded my glove package as follows:

```
import gensim.downloader as api
model = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100")
```

and would want to create a function where I pass in a word and the GloVe model, and it will return the corresponding vector, for instance,

```
def convert_word_to_vec(word, model):
```

and when I pass in `convert_word_to_vec(lol, model)` it will return the vectors for the word `lol`

Is there a way around this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage:

```
import gensim.downloader as api
model = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100")

vector = model['lol']
print(vector)  # array with shape (100,)
```

Please check the documentations for more options:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html